# Подскажите в чем ошибка кода

Tags: javascript

Написал конвертер величин но почему-то **не вычисляет** **и выводит везде "0",** подскажите почему? Если не затруднит Вас напишите кусок js чтобы выводило результат(

```html
<html>
    <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <head/>
    <body>
        <form>
            <label>Enter a value</label>
            <select name="from" id="from">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">Killometres</option>
                <option value="1">Milles</option>
                <option value="2">Futs</option>
    <option value="2">Yards</option>
    <option value="2">Dums</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <label>Enter a count </label>
            <input name="cash" id="cash" class="is" type="text"/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <label>Enter a change value </label>
            <select name="to" id="to">
                <option value="0" >Killometres</option>
                <option value="1"selected="selected">Milles</option>
                <option value="2">Futs</option>
    <option value="3">Yards</option>
    <option value="4">Dums</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <input type=button value="Convert" onclick='GiveResult();'>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <label><span id="result" class="result"></span></label>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            c = new Array();
            n = new Array();
            c[0] = 1;
            n[0] = "Killometres";
            c[1] = 0,62;
            n[1] = "Milles";
            c[2] = 4;
            n[2] = "Futs";
   c[3] = 5;
            n[3] = "Yards";
   c[4] = 6;
            n[4] = "Dums";
     
            function GiveResult()
            {
                var res, vfrom, vto, vcash;
                vcash = document.getElementById("cash").value;
                vfrom = document.getElementById("from").value;
                vcash = vcash.replace(',', '\.');
                vcash = vcash.replace(' ', '');
                vcash = vcash.replace(' ', '');
                vto = document.getElementById("to").value;
                res = c[vto] * vcash / c[vfrom], 2;
                res = res.toFixed(0);
                res = res.toString();
                res = res.replace('\.', ',');
                res = "<span class='result'> Результат перевода: " + res + "</span>&nbsp;" + n[vto];
            
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = res;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: что значат следующие строки: `c[1] = 0,62;` и `c[vfrom], 2`?

Comment: 1 км=0.62мили, vfrom = document.getElementById("from").value; а фром  идентификатов величины которую я выбрал но почему то выводит 0

Comment: даже когда убрал vfrom даже не множит  res = c[vto] * vcash;

Answer (score 1):

Как Grundy показал выше первое, что мешает это `c[1] = 0,62` => `c[1] = 0.62`
и двойка в вычислениях...  `res = c[vto] * vcash / c[vfrom], 2;`

```js
c = new Array();
 n = new Array();
 c[0] = 1;
 n[0] = "Killometres";
 c[1] = 0.62
 n[1] = "Milles";
 c[2] = 4;
 n[2] = "Futs";
 c[3] = 5;
 n[3] = "Yards";
 c[4] = 6;
 n[4] = "Dums";

 function GiveResult() {
   var res, vfrom, vto, vcash;
   vcash = document.getElementById("cash").value;
   vfrom = document.getElementById("from").value;
   vto = document.getElementById("to").value;
   res = c[vto] * vcash / c[vfrom];
   res = res.toFixed(2);
   res = res.toString();
  
   res = "<span class='result'> Результат перевода: " + res + "</span>&nbsp;" + n[vto];

   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = res;
 }
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Enter a value</label>
  <select name="from" id="from">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Killometres</option>
    <option value="1">Milles</option>
    <option value="2">Futs</option>
    <option value="2">Yards</option>
    <option value="2">Dums</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <label>Enter a count</label>
  <input name="cash" id="cash" class="is" type="text" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <label>Enter a change value</label>
  <select name="to" id="to">
    <option value="0">Killometres</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Milles</option>
    <option value="2">Futs</option>
    <option value="3">Yards</option>
    <option value="4">Dums</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <input type=button value="Convert" onclick='GiveResult();'>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <label><span id="result" class="result"></span>
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: последняя двойка, кстати, не мешает. Она просто ничего не делает

Comment: @Grundy согласен..

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в [операторе `,`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F), который используется в строке

```
c[1] = 0,62;
```

В результате выполнения этой строки, значение ячейки будет не ожидаемые `0.62`, а `0`. Поэтому при использовании этого значения в формуле

```
c[vto] * vcash / c[vfrom]
```

В результате будет `0` либо `Infinity`

Кроме того, неясна цель использования оператора `,` в строке

```
res = c[vto] * vcash / c[vfrom], 2;
```

Следующее замечание по работе с введенными данными:

нет нужды писать replace в отдельной строке, так как эта функция возвращает строку, следующую можно применить сразу к результату. Кроме того не совсем понятна логика: убираются и пробельный символ, и символ `,` меняется на `.`

Вместо этого можно использовать следующий подход

```
.replace(/\s+/g,'').replace(',','.');
```

После изменения, лучше привести строку к числу, например с помощью [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Следующее: работа с результатом.

[toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) уже возвращает строку. Нет нужды еще раз вызывать `toString`. При замене точки на запятую нет нужды экранировать точку, потому что используется строка, а не регулярное выражение.

Далее:

Массивы можно объявить сразу заполненные, с помощью литерала массива `[...]`

например: `c = [1,0.62,4,5,6]`

И последнее: `.toFixed(0)`, округлит число до целого, и если результат был меньше `0.5`, в ответе будет `0`.

В итоге может получиться примерно так:

```js
c = [1, 0.62, 4, 5, 6];
n = ["Killometres", "Milles", "Futs", "Yards", "Dums"];

function GiveResult() {
  var res, vfrom, vto, vcash;
  vfrom = document.getElementById("from").value;
  vcash = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cash").value.replace(',', '.').replace(/\s+/g, ''));
  vto = document.getElementById("to").value;
  res = (c[vto] * vcash / c[vfrom]).toFixed(0).replace('.', ',');
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<span class='result'> Результат перевода: " + res + "</span>&nbsp;" + n[vto];
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Enter a value</label>
  <select name="from" id="from">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Killometres</option>
    <option value="1">Milles</option>
    <option value="2">Futs</option>
    <option value="2">Yards</option>
    <option value="2">Dums</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <label>Enter a count</label>
  <input name="cash" id="cash" class="is" type="text" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <label>Enter a change value</label>
  <select name="to" id="to">
    <option value="0">Killometres</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Milles</option>
    <option value="2">Futs</option>
    <option value="3">Yards</option>
    <option value="4">Dums</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <input type=button value="Convert" onclick='GiveResult();'>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <label><span id="result" class="result"></span>
  </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас `с[vform]` = undefined, а в строке

```
res = c[vto] * vcash / c[vfrom], 2;
```

Идет деление на него. Соответственно, на 0. В итоге и получается 0.

Comment: в приведенной строки не используется `res[vform]`

Comment: @Grundy уже заметил, исправил, спасибо.

Comment: ну и тогда уж не `NULL` - в яваскрипте этого вообще нет, а _undefined_

Comment: @Grundy главное, что бы было понятно, что у элемента массива нет значения. Еще раз спасибо, что поправили)